# Angular 1.0.8 code does not work in 1.6.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just started learning angular-js today. So was trying some old examples.

There is a backend api which gives me a json list. I am trying to consume that and show some stuff.

Got the examples in version `1.0.8` and it works fine. But when i try the same with version `1.6.5`, it does not work at all. What changed? How can i make this work?

**Files**

```js
function Books($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/book-manager/bookslist.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.books = data;
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Angular</title>
<!-- 1.0.8 Working -->
<script src="angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- 1.6.5 Not Working, Why? -->
<!-- <script src="angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="count.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="Books">
  I have {{books.length}} books!
  <ul class="books-container">
   <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.name}}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should look up the differences between 1.0.8 and 1.6.5...

Comment: @WilliamHampshire I should... but its too much for me as i just started today and i mentioned that in the question clearly. As its a very small example, i thought some pros can help me?. Thats all. Thanks  for marking not useful.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question and why are they doing so without the courtesy of an explanation?

Comment: do you have that controller declared as a controller using `angular.module().controller()` first? Open your browser console and see if it is giving you any messages.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D : Nope. What you see in the question is all of it. Nothing extra. Should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One large change was how you declare a controller in your angular app. You will need to have your main `ng-app` module, and add a controller to it (which you can still use the Books function you have).

**count.js**

```
angular.module('mainAppExample', []).controller('Books', Books);
function Books(){}
```

Remember to also add the `ng-app` directive which is your root module (that you can add multiple controllers, filters, and other directives to). This will usually go in a root element tag like `<html>` or `<body>`:

**books.html**

```
<body ng-app="mainAppExample">
    <div ng-controller="Books">
        I have {{books.length}} books!
        <ul class="books-container">
            <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

- [1.0.8 ng-controller](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.directive:ngController)
- [1.6.5 ng-controller](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/docs/api/ng/directive/ngController)
- [1.6.5 ng-app](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/docs/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

Comment: Thank You sir. I followed the docs suggested by you and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Success is deprecated. You should use then instead.

```
function Books($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/book-manager/bookslist.json').then(function(data) {
        $scope.books = data;
    });
}
```

You are also probably getting a complete response object back in 1.6.5 so, try this if the above still fails:

```
function Books($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/book-manager/bookslist.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.books = response.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: deprecated means is still working, but better to move forward into something else, he said it is not working at all.

Comment: Actually in 1.6.5 all of the deprecated callbacks were finally removed.

Comment: So it is called removed not deprecated, you right it was deprecated in version 1.5, but removed later, I'm just saying using "deprecated" word is not accurate.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Tried it, but same output. Maybe some other reason?

Comment: @MikeFeltman: I get this output `I have {{books.length}} books!`. So maybe its not resolving the `{{}}` like it did in `1.0.8`

Comment: Not sure I'm following you now. Are you saying it's working?

Comment: In `1.0.8`, i get `I have 2 books!`. FYI, Json array size is 2.

Comment: add console.log(response) to your function right before $scope.books = response.data and tell us what's in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155353/discussion-between-rajkishan-and-mike-feltman).

Answer (score 1):

The version between 1.0 and 1.6 is a really big gap and got tons of changes, the legacy version you need to target first is 1.2x then you need to migrate to 1.3 then 1.4 to 1.5, you really need to review changelogs here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

So it could be better to see the breaking changes at least.

In version 1.5 and later it is use promises, so you have to use something like:

```
$http.get(URL).then(function(data) {
        //handle success 
    }, function (error) {
        //handle error
    });
```

Anyway, it will not stop to this issue, you really need to review all changes.

I prefer to look into Angular (not AngularJS) anyway if you have a small project it is worth to learn something new.

**Edit**:
If you really new to AngularJs, I would say it is not worth to learn it, it will live for a short/medium term, go for Angular (version 4+).